# Notice period question

Tags: interviewing

I just had an interview, before the interview ended the job interviewer asked me a last question which was to confirm that my notice period is 1 month.

Should i look into anything significant to this question? Good sign or just a casual question? Is this a good sign that i stand a chance of getting a job offer or the notice period question asked is just for confirmation purposes?

Comment: A standard question. They just want to know, if they were to offer you the job, how soon after they made the offer could you start. I've been asked this both in cases where I did and I didn't get the job.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bad question. It's important for them to know your notice period for logistical reasons, ie,. when can you start etc,.

Don't read anything bad into it, it's positive or neutral at worst.